# Can not inherit from final class

Tags: java, android, android-library, kotlin-android-extensions

I have just created my first android library. At another application I want to extend a class from the it. But it shows me an error: "Cannot extend from final 'library.com.kukaintro.activities.KukaIntro'".[image]

[image]

As you can see none of the super classes are final. If I click at the super class KukaIntro (at the app not at the library) it says this: 
[image]

This is my first time creatin a library. Can someone show me how can I manage to fix this problem?

Comment: Don't use screen shots. Code is text, so post it as formatted text in your question!

Comment: Hi. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then share a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your code or whatever you have done or tried so far to solve the problem.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In Kotlin, unlike Java, all the classes are implicitly marked `final` by default. If you want to inherit from a class, you have to explicitly add `open` keyword before the class declaration.

```
open class Base(p: Int) {

}
```

If you want to override any functions from the super class, again you have to add the `open` keyword to those functions in the super class, and the `override` keyword is mandatory for the overridden function in the sub class.

Example from the doc:

```
open class Foo {
    open fun f() { println("Foo.f()") }
    open val x: Int get() = 1
}

class Bar : Foo() {
    override fun f() { 
        super.f()
        println("Bar.f()") 
    }

    override val x: Int get() = super.x + 1
}
```

Kotlin docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance

Here is the discussion about this language design: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/classes-final-by-default/166

Comment: Thanks, but can you help me more specifically? Class KukaIntro extends KukaIntroBase. Should I type "open" before declaring KukaIntroBase? When I do this, android studio says: "Modifier open is redundant because abstract is present".

Comment: Add 'open' to KukaIntro class.

Comment: If it's working would you please mark it as correct.

Comment: It is. Thank you sir. You were a great help!

Answer (score 2):

Use the open annotation, read the documentation here.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html